# Do you know the Maven profile for mvnrepository.com?

Tags: maven-2, maven, dependencies, profile, dependency-management

I am trying to include some dependencies in my Maven project. These dependencies are not available in the default Maven 2 repository http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.

They are available at http://mvnrepository.com/.

But I couldn't find the profile for this site to include in my `settings.xml`.

Does anyone know what this repository's URL and profile is?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Once you've found your jar through mvnrepository.com, hover the "download (JAR)" link, and you'll see the link to the repository which contains your jar (you can probably Right clic and "Copy link URL" to get the URL, what ever your browser is).

Then, you have to add this repository to the repositories used by your project, in your pom.xml :

```
<project>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-alternate-repository</id>
      <url>http://myrepo.net/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

EDIT : now MVNrepository.com has evolved : You can find the link to the repository in the "Repositories" section :

License

Categories

HomePage

Date

Files

**Repositories**

Comment: This is a great answer, you may also want to include the `snapshots` and `releases` options shown below by Nicolas.

Comment: There is no download jar link

Comment: Just to note that if you search for the details on http://search.maven.org or http://mvnrepository.com  when you find the project you want you should see the projects pom.xml, open this and then search for url, eventually you will likely see a tag <distributionManagement><repository> that has the URL details within it. You can then navigate to this url in your browser, and see if you can find the required jar files etc. Otherwise, search on the other URLs that are picked up

Comment: You can add this repositories to your active profile in settings.xml , if you want to go global on the whole m2 repo. Most of this repositories are used in most of the projects, so to add them individually to every pom is too much.

Comment: When I right click on my dependency's jar, I get a url.  That url is not the url for the repository for that dependency.  I see on the mvnrepository page for the dependency that the the artifact is located at a certain repository.  I hit that url, it's a nexus repository.  I can browse the repository, but the url for that repository won't work in my project's pom (of course).  I look at the pom for that dependency as suggested above; no url in that pom.  Why is this so hard?

Answer (score 52):

mvnrepository.com isn't a repository. It's a search engine. It might or might not tell you what repository it found stuff in if it's not central; since you didn't post an example, I can't help you read the output.

Comment: I will counter the part where "it might or might not tell you what repository it found stuff in". It works with Maven Central. Otherwise, yes, this isn't an actual Maven Repository, but just a search engine for dependencies.

Comment: I was looking for this:
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

but could not find it in repo1.maven.org

Comment: That one is 'special'. Better to use Geronimo. But if you must, it happens to live at java.net.

Comment: @carl it looks at more than maven central, and the answer above shows that it does reveal where it found any given thing.

Comment: This answer would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: That comment would be more appropriate six years ago.

Comment: mvnrepository its the not the official one, the official is search.maven.org/
As mentioned here: https://central.sonatype.org/search/

Answer (score 21):

You can put this configuration in your settings.xml file:

```
            <repository>
                <id>mvnrepository</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
```

Comment: This is central, not mvn.

Answer (score 10):

Please use this profile

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>mvnrepository</id>
                <name>mvnrepository</name>
                <url>http://www.mvnrepository.com</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>mvnrepository</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

Comment: I wouldn't profess to be a Maven expert, but why do other answers say that mvnrepository isn't a repository when this works? (Even if it's a "proxy" for other repositories)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It needs an id on the profile, then I need to link the profile in activeProfiles instead of the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the `~/.m2/settings.xml` or custom file to be run with `$ mvn -s custom-settings.xml install`

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
<interactiveMode/>
<offline/>
<pluginGroups/>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>mvnrepository</id>
                <name>mvnrepository</name>
                <url>http://www.mvnrepository.com</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>mvnrepository</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

            <!--
            Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
            or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
            distributed with this work for additional information
            regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
            to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
            "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
            with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
                http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
            Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
            software distributed under the License is distributed on an
            "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
            KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
            specific language governing permissions and limitations
            under the License.
            -->

            <!--
             | This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:
             |
             |  1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user,
             |                 and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
             |
             |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
             |
             |                 -s /path/to/user/settings.xml
             |
             |  2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all Maven
             |                 users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven
             |                 installation). It's normally provided in
             |                 ${maven.conf}/settings.xml.
             |
             |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
             |
             |                 -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml
             |
             | The sections in this sample file are intended to give you a running start at
             | getting the most out of your Maven installation. Where appropriate, the default
             | values (values used when the setting is not specified) are provided.
             |
             |-->
            <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
              <!-- localRepository
               | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
               |
               | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
              <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
              -->

              <!-- interactiveMode
               | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,
               | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for
               | the parameter in question.
               |
               | Default: true
              <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
              -->

              <!-- offline
               | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.
               | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
               |
               | Default: false
              <offline>false</offline>
              -->

              <!-- pluginGroups
               | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.
               | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
               | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.
               |-->
              <pluginGroups>
                <!-- pluginGroup
                 | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
                <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
                -->
              </pluginGroups>

              <!-- proxies
               | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
               | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
               | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
               |-->
              <proxies>
                <!-- proxy
                 | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
                 |
                <proxy>
                  <id>optional</id>
                  <active>false</active>
                  <protocol>http</protocol>
                  <username>proxyuser</username>
                  <password>proxypass</password>
                  <host>proxy.host.net</host>
                  <port>80</port>
                  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
                </proxy>
                -->
              </proxies>

              <!-- servers
               | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
               | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
               |-->
              <servers>
                <!-- server
                 | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by
                 | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).
                 |
                 | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are
                 |       used together.
                 |
                <server>
                  <id>deploymentRepo</id>
                  <username>repouser</username>
                  <password>repopwd</password>
                </server>
                -->

                <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.
                <server>
                  <id>siteServer</id>
                  <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
                  <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
                </server>
                -->
              </servers>

              <!-- mirrors
               | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts from remote repositories.
               |
               | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository to use in resolving certain artifacts.
               | However, this repository may have problems with heavy traffic at times, so people have mirrored
               | it to several places.
               |
               | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create a mirror reference for that
               | repository, to be used as an alternate download site. The mirror site will be the preferred
               | server for that repository.
               |-->
              <mirrors>
                <!-- mirror
                 | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
                 | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
                 | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
                 |
                <mirror>
                  <id>mirrorId</id>
                  <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
                  <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
                  <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
                </mirror>
                 -->
              </mirrors>

              <!-- profiles
               | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety of ways, and which can modify
               | the build process. Profiles provided in the settings.xml are intended to provide local machine-
               | specific paths and repository locations which allow the build to work in the local environment.
               |
               | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus - that needs to know where
               | your Tomcat instance is installed, you can provide a variable here such that the variable is
               | dereferenced during the build process to configure the cactus plugin.
               |
               | As noted above, profiles can be activated in a variety of ways. One way - the activeProfiles
               | section of this document (settings.xml) - will be discussed later. Another way essentially
               | relies on the detection of a system property, either matching a particular value for the property,
               | or merely testing its existence. Profiles can also be activated by JDK version prefix, where a
               | value of '1.4' might activate a profile when the build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'.
               | Finally, the list of active profiles can be specified directly from the command line.
               |
               | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to specifying only artifact
               |       repositories, plugin repositories, and free-form properties to be used as configuration
               |       variables for plugins in the POM.
               |
               |-->
              <profiles>

              <profile>
                <id>maven-https</id>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
                <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>central</id>
                        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </repository>
                </repositories>
                <pluginRepositories>
                    <pluginRepository>
                        <id>central</id>
                        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </pluginRepository>
                </pluginRepositories> 
            </profile>

                <!-- profile
                 | Specifies a set of introductions to the build process, to be activated using one or more of the
                 | mechanisms described above. For inheritance purposes, and to activate profiles via <activatedProfiles/>
                 | or the command line, profiles have to have an ID that is unique.
                 |
                 | An encouraged best practice for profile identification is to use a consistent naming convention
                 | for profiles, such as 'env-dev', 'env-test', 'env-production', 'user-jdcasey', 'user-brett', etc.
                 | This will make it more intuitive to understand what the set of introduced profiles is attempting
                 | to accomplish, particularly when you only have a list of profile id's for debug.
                 |
                 | This profile example uses the JDK version to trigger activation, and provides a JDK-specific repo.
                <profile>
                  <id>jdk-1.4</id>
                  <activation>
                    <jdk>1.4</jdk>
                  </activation>
                  <repositories>
                    <repository>
                      <id>jdk14</id>
                      <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
                      <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
                      <layout>default</layout>
                      <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
                    </repository>

                  </repositories>
                </profile>
                -->

                <!--
                 | Here is another profile, activated by the system property 'target-env' with a value of 'dev',
                 | which provides a specific path to the Tomcat instance. To use this, your plugin configuration
                 | might hypothetically look like:
                 |
                 | ...
                 | <plugin>
                 |   <groupId>org.myco.myplugins</groupId>
                 |   <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>
                 |
                 |   <configuration>
                 |     <tomcatLocation>${tomcatPath}</tomcatLocation>
                 |   </configuration>
                 | </plugin>
                 | ...
                 |
                 | NOTE: If you just wanted to inject this configuration whenever someone set 'target-env' to
                 |       anything, you could just leave off the <value/> inside the activation-property.
                 |
                <profile>
                  <id>env-dev</id>
                  <activation>
                    <property>
                      <name>target-env</name>
                      <value>dev</value>
                    </property>
                  </activation>
                  <properties>
                    <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>
                  </properties>
                </profile>
                -->
              </profiles>

              <!-- activeProfiles
               | List of profiles that are active for all builds.
               |
              <activeProfiles>
                <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
                <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
              </activeProfiles>
              -->
            </settings>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.