# Maven repo does not work

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to add a maven repository `mvnrepository.com`, but it seems that I fail doing this.

```
<repository>
    <id>mvnrepository</id>
    <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/</url>         
</repository>
```

I can clearly see that the artifact I am looking for is there http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE

But my maven build output reports me that it's not

> Downloading:
>   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact//org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
>   [INFO] Unable to find resource
>   'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE' in repository
>   mvnrepository (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/)

What am I doing wrong? How can I download spring ldap artifact?

**UPDATE**
I have tried several artifactories, but all of them fail

> Downloading:
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2//org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
>   [INFO] Unable to find resource
>   'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE' in repository
>   maven central repo (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) Downloading:
>   http://download.java.net/maven/2//org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
>   [INFO] Unable to find resource
>   'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE' in repository
>   java.net repo (http://download.java.net/maven/2/) Downloading:
>   http://maven.springframework.org/external//org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
>   [INFO] Unable to find resource
>   'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE' in repository
>   spring external (http://maven.springframework.org/external/)
>   Downloading:
>   http://search.maven.org//org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
>   [INFO] Unable to find resource
>   'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE' in repository
>   repo.jenkins-ci.org (http://search.maven.org/) Downloading:
>   https://repository.jboss.org//org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
>   [INFO] Unable to find resource
>   'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE' in repository
>   mvnrepository (https://repository.jboss.org/) Downloading:
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2//org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
>   [INFO] Unable to find resource
>   'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE' in repository
>   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)

If I do not define any repositories in settings.xml, then the response is the following:

> Downloading:
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
>   [INFO] Unable to find resource
>   'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE' in repository
>   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

**UPDATE**
Besides, I use gradle in other projects, and this works seamlessly

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap:1.3.1.RELEASE'
}
```

So I am pretty sure there is some maven repo I don't know about

Comment: Why would you like to add that. What you are searching for spring-ldap is available in Maven Central so this is configured by default and so no need to change/add repositories in this case

Comment: [mvnrepository isn't a repository but a search engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625752/do-you-know-the-maven-profile-for-mvnrepository-com).  You should not add it to your repositories

Comment: have you a proxy in your net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spring-ldap artifact is pom type. To specify any artifact other than jar you need to specify the type. So the artifact you need to specify in your pom is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Apologies, techboost. I did not see your `<type>pom</type>`. Works perfectly. Sorry once again.

Answer (score 1):

As @techbost mentioned, maven can't resolve spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar from any repository, because such jar does not exist.

Let's see what's going on. You define your dependency in the following way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't specify a `type` tag, the default type is `jar`. Which means that Maven tries to hit this URL to get the file:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar

As you see, this file does not exist. That's because the `spring-ldap` module does not have a jar, it's a `pom` packaging module, which means it only has pom file, which has common configuration for submodules and definition of those submodules.

Next you might want to define a type to be `pom`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

One might think that should work, because now you instruct maven to download a pom file, which does exist:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.1.RELEASE.pom

Well, it won't work as well. That's because `pom` artifact is not a real dependency (just for reminder - dependencies are files that added to your classpath for compilation, testing and packaging, so it makes no sense to have a pom file in classpath).

What you actually need is one of the two:

- Use specific submodule of spring-ldap, e.g. `spring-ldap-core`.
- Use the `all` classifer of `spring-ldap` module. In this case you'll bring *all* the modules, in a single jar. Although it might ease your configuration, it's strongly discouraged particle.

In the former case, your dependency declaration will look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This works.

In the later case your dependency declaration will be as following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <classifier>all</classifier>
</dependency>
```

This works as well, although it's really bad idea.

P.S. mvnrepository site is not a *real* maven repository. It's a site for searching and browsing artifacts in maven-central and was usable when maven central didn't have search.

The two repositories I can suggest are:

1. `jcenter` - superset of Maven Central, https by default, web identity of the publishers, richer UI, etc. See https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter for more details (`Set me up` button will give you instructions on how to use it with Maven)
2. Maven Central over https - [here](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/consumers.html#apache-maven) are the Maven setup instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add any extra repository tag to fetch spring-ldap artifact.

You only need to specify the repository when the artifact doesn't belong to the default maven repo for e.g., Jboss Repository https://repository.jboss.org/, you need to add this in your pom to fetch any artifact of this repository.

you simple add below dependency in your pom and it should work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Are you having any problem in downloading artifact without specifying repository?

Comment: The spring artifact is available in Maven Central. So no need for supplemental repositories. http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.springframework.ldap%22%20a%3A%22spring-ldap%22

Comment: I updated my answer with the latest logs of maven build.