# Maven Settings.xml Add Multiple Servers With Priority

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

My work has its own maven server that it uses. Unfortunately, when I try to add a dependency to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbutils/commons-dbutils/1.6 it is not being found.

My question is how do I modify my `settings.xml` to allow for a 2nd server, which would be the `mvnrepository`, but only reference that server if the dependency isn't found on the main server?

Comment: did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065165/maven-repository-lookup-order

Comment: @A. Di Matteo, Thanks the link didn't quite give me what I needed, but lead me down the road of being able to do other googles/searches and get closer to what I needed. I posted an answer below as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some search on stack overflow, I found the following answer to be useful: [Do you know the maven profile for mvnrepository.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625752/do-you-know-the-maven-profile-for-mvnrepository-com)

I did a combination of Tristan and Nicolas' answers, which let me add the following into my settings.xml:

```
<repository>
  <id>maven repo</id>
  <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</endabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
</repository>
```

Closed my project, reopened then reimported the maven dependences and all was good.